# How to download atmospheric/oceanographic data for a given region in the sea?

Tags: meteorology, oceanography, temperature, weather-satellites

I am trying to get data of atmospheric temperature, wind intensity and/or atmospheric pressure for a specific region of the sea, since I have ocean bottom pressure data from a fixed instrument (lat,long), so I need to compare it with other variables. I have read in many articles that it could be obtained from satellite data. Can anyone help me with how to do that or guide me how to get the series? As you know it is not possible for a specific point in the sea, but the data for a given region (grid) works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want satellite data, you could use the [Copernicus system](https://www.copernicus.eu/en/copernicus-satellite-data-access), which won't, however, provide you with the required variables, but the measured variables directly AFAIK (irradiance in various bandwidths).

The usual approach would be to use reanalysis data, which you can get from the various organisations providing it like ERA5 from the [CDS](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/#!/home) or [NCEP](https://www.psl.noaa.gov/data/reanalysis/) from NOAA.